# Solving $\cos \frac{165}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

What are the steps to solve $$\frac{\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}(2\sqrt{2}-1-\sqrt3)}}{4}$$ into $$\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}{2}$$

Please explain. I got them from derivation of $$\cos(82.5^\circ)$$ in 2 different ways. 
$$\cos(60^\circ+22.5^\circ)$$ and $$\cos\frac{(90^\circ+75^\circ)}{2}$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit your question please? $165$ are degrees.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{4/\sqrt{2}}$ so you have
$$
\begin{split}
f &= \frac{\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}(2\sqrt{2}-1-\sqrt3)}}{4} \\
  &= \frac12 \sqrt{\frac{2\sqrt{2}-1-\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}} \\
  &= \frac12 \sqrt{2 - \frac{1+\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}}
\end{split}
$$
so remains to prove that $$ \frac{1 + \sqrt{3}}{\sqrt2} = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$$

To do that,multiply by $\sqrt2$ and square both sides to get
$$
1^2 + 3 + 2\sqrt{3} = 2(2+\sqrt3)
$$
which are obviously equal to $4+2\sqrt3$.

Comment: Very nice, and my compliments.

Answer (score 2):

If we are allowed to solve analytically then

\begin{align}2\sqrt{2}(2\sqrt{2}-1-\sqrt3)&=
4\sqrt{4}-2\sqrt{2}-2\sqrt{6}\\&=
8-2(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6})\\&=
8-2\left(2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}\right)\\&=
8-4\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}\\&=
4\left(2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}\right)
\end{align}

so that

$$\frac{\sqrt{4\left(2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}\right)}}{4}=\frac{2\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}{2}$$